# convenience init causes crash under release build configuration

Tags: ios, swift

Is it compiler bug, or someone know what may be wrong with the code?
This code for the new project with Single View Application template.
To crash the app you can replace default code in AppDelegate.swift onto this one:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow? = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CrashController())
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}

//======================================================================================================================

class CrashController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        navigationItem.title = "Optimisation is not always Good"

        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Crash the App Under Release", for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: 300, height: 50)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onCrashButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @IBAction func onCrashButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let goodItem = SomeItem(text: "1") // This Item will BE stored properly
        let badItem = SomeItem(textWithCrash: "2") // This Item will NOT be stored properly

        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            print(goodItem.text)
            print(badItem.text) // EXC_BAD_ACCESS under Release
        }

        print(goodItem.text)
        print(badItem.text)
    }
}

//======================================================================================================================

class SomeItem {
    var text = ""

    deinit {
        print("deinit \(self.text)")
    }

    // required initializer
    required init(textWithoutCrash: String) {
        self.text = textWithoutCrash
        print("required init \(self.text)")
    }

    // designated initializer
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
        print("designated init \(self.text)")
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // DANGEROUS convenience initializer !!! App will BE crashed under Release Build Configeration
    //
    // calling required initializer inside convenience initializer is DANGEROUS under release with optimization:
    // ENABLE_TESTABILITY = NO
    // SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = -Owholemodule
    //
    // There is NO crash Under Debug Build Configeration without optimisation:
    // ENABLE_TESTABILITY = YES
    // SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = -Onone
    //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    convenience init(textWithCrash: String) {

        // App will NOT be crashed calling designated initializer
//        self.init(text: textWithCrash)

        // App will be CRASHED later due to calling required initializer inside convenience initializer
        self.init(textWithoutCrash: textWithCrash)
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Optimisation causes crash ONLY if
// - the class has convenience init
// - the required initializer is calling inside the convenience init
// - the class has any children, (anyone inherits from the class) even if children does not use at all
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class SomeChildItem: SomeItem {
//    // implementing required initializer does not help - App will be crashed anyway
//    required init(textWithoutCrash: String) {
//        super.init(textWithoutCrash: textWithoutCrash)
//    }
//
//    // overriding designated initializer does not help - App will be crashed anyway
//    override init(text: String) {
//        super.init(text: text)
//    }
//
//    // implementing convenience initializer does not help - App will be crashed anyway
//    convenience init(textWithCrash: String) {
//        self.init(textWithoutCrash: textWithCrash)
//    }
}
```

There is no crash under Debug, but the crash happens only if you select Build configuration `Release` in Menu bar: Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme or just pressed `Cmd-Shift-<` hot key. Or in production version if you create an archive.

---

I can found that the app is crashed with default settings under Release:

- ENABLE_TESTABILITY = NO
- SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = -Owholemodule

The app is not crashed with default settings under Debug:

- ENABLE_TESTABILITY = YES
- SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = -Onone

And some conditions for the crash:

- the class has convenience init;
- the required initializer is calling inside the convenience init;
- the class has any children even empty not used children;

---

I did not find in Apple documentation any taboo on calling required initializer from convenience initializers. Moreover, Apple's doc "The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.0.1)" has phrase "You do not write the override modifier when overriding a required designated initializer" which means that required is also designated. So, it may be called from convenience.
I'm using Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62) with Swift 3.0.1.
Any ideas?

---

UPDATE1:
Version of onCrashButton without DispatchQueue.main.async, so if you access to bad item in next runloop it will be BAD_ACCESS and crash.

```
var someItems = [SomeItem]()

@IBAction func onCrashButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("someItems: \(someItems.count)")

    if let someItem = someItems.last {
        // Any Access to someItem is BAD_ACCESS and crashes the App. Why?
        let text = someItem.text
        print("text: \(text)")
    }

    // This Item will BE stored properly.
    someItems += [SomeItem(text: "Some text \(someItems.count)")]

    // This Item will NOT be stored into array properly. Why?
    someItems += [SomeItem(textWithCrash: "Some text \(someItems.count)")]
}
```

Comment: note that `@IBAction` are triggered on the main queue, so `DispatchQueue.main.async` shouldn't be needed.

Comment: yes, you are right about the main queue, but without DispatchQueue.main.async there is no crash. badItem will be destroyed only in next runloop. So, to crash you should access badItem in the next runloop, via DispatchQueue.main.async or any other @IBAction or event.

Comment: It is a bug in Xcode 8.2. So, I created a bug #29398625 on bugreport.apple.com. Now, Apple has fixed the issue in Xcode 8.3 beta 2 (8W120l).